# What is the Martian Empire?

Tags: star-trek

In [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65758/why-is-federation-space-divided) question, I couldn't help but notice that the third starmap listed contains a territory called the "Martian Empire".

[image: Map of star trek universe with a territory called the "Martian Empire", above the Gardian Republic]

I could not find any reference to this Empire in Memory Alpha or Memory Beta via an (albeit) brief search, and I also noted that the other starmaps in that post do not have this space marked off, instead they have that area mostly empty, with a much smaller territory called the "Typhon Expanse" almost dead centre (Although this could be a result of the lossy 3d -> 2d conversion).

[image: Map of star trek universe with a territory called the "Typhon Expanse", in place of the "Martian Empire"]

So, finally my questions:

**What is the canonicity of this "Martian Empire"?**

**In what shows/books/etc. was it mentioned?**

**And when was (-will?) it supposed to have existed)?**

Comment: These seem like 3 different question, but given the dubious nature of canonicity, I think they're related enough to stand as one. *(Just a pre-emptive thought.)*

Comment: @MeatTrademark That's what I figured as well :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## There is no canonicity for a "Martian Empire" in Star Trek.  The map that mentions it is a fan-produced work pertaining to an online sci-fi role-playing community.

There are absolutely no references to a "Martian Empire" in Alpha or Beta Star Trek material.

The map you have posted is not canon whatsoever.  It is a fan-made map, designed by a member of the **"Pheonix Command Group"**.  It is an online role-playing community focused on science fiction works — mainly Star Trek but also some other franchises.

The history of the map is here:

- ["Official" PCG Universe Map](http://phoenixcommandgroup.forumotion.com/t167-the-official-pcg-universe-map)

The group's writings on a "Martian Empire" can be found [here](http://phoenixcommandgroup.forumotion.com/f39-martian-empire).

Comment: Ah, okay. I figured that it would be something like that. Thank you!

Comment: @FinnO'leary : Glad to be of help. :-)